# Problem sorting Swedish characters Å Ä Ö MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, character

I'm trying to sort a list with asc or desc - depending on what the user choose. In the list I have the Swedish characters Å Ä Ö and it's here the problem shows up. I have the following list:

```
(First list)
Stängd
Stängd
Öppen
Krävs ej
Krävs ej
```

(Standing for; Stängd = Closed, Öppen = Opened, Krävs ej = Not required)

The list should be sorted - depending on what the user choose;

```
Öppen
Stängd
Stängd
Krävs ej
Krävs ej
```

or

```
Krävs ej 
Krävs ej
Stängd 
Stängd 
Öppen
```

But as it is now the first list is showing up. So the problem is the "Ö" -character. My database and the field that the value is in have the collation utf8_general_ci, so that is'nt the problem. And the character "Ö" is right in both database (looking throu PHPMyAdmin) and output right when printing it out.

My code look like this:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '$sort_by'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'sida'
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value $sort_order";
```

How can this appear and how does I solve it?

Comment: I think o with umlaut is at the end of the alphabet in the Swedish alphabet

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> My database and the field that the value is in have the collation utf8_general_ci, so that is'nt the problem

But it is. :) Different collations have different sort orders, and different ways how they interpret umlauts.

`utf8_general_ci` will sort `Ö` with `O`. Try the `utf8_swedish_ci` instead. That will have the correct sorting order, which (IIRC) is that `ÄAÖ` go to the end of the alphabet.

For background info, see [9.1.7.8. Examples of the Effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Comment: Awsome! That did the trick. Then I was wrong. You learn something new everyday. Thanks again!

Comment: While I already knew that swedish collation would fix the sorting, I didn't realize that you need to refill the table in order to make it work. I tried that after confirming the solution here and it worked.

Comment: refilling the table is not needded. Allthough changing the collation on the columns might be needed.

Answer (score 7):

The [general collation](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html) places `Ö` with `O`. If you want `Ö` at the end of the alphabet then you need to use [`utf8_swedish_ci`](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_swedish_ci.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert existing tables to a new collation, just use the following:

```
alter table [tableName] convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924382/how-to-change-column-collation-postgresql