# MySQL compare string with national characters

Tags: mysql, string

I got a small trouble:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName tn WHERE LOWER(tn.name) = LOWER('place_string_here');
```

It's ok, when it does a perfect fit:

> tn.name = **orange_tree**
>
> place_string_here = **Orange_Tree**

But my issue is: national characters, eg.:

> Hästgård

I wish "Hästgård" to fit:
Hästgård,
Hästgard,
Hastgård and/or
Hastgard

Is there any smart way to do that?

Comment: which charset are you using (and collation)

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529013/problem-sorting-swedish-characters-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the latin1_swedish_ci COLLATION on that field, which causes the error.
After changing collation to utf8_general_ci (of the "name" field), It started working properly :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

Your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName tn 
WHERE tn.name COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' = 'place_string_here'
```

**[SQLFIDDLExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d16/1)**

```
VALUES
('Hästgård', 'admin@sqlfiddle.com'),
('Twitter', '@sqlfiddle');
```

Query:

```
select id, type
from t
where type COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' = 'hastgard'
```

Result:

```
| ID |     TYPE |
-----------------
|  1 | Hästgård |
```