# Wordpress get_pages sort by post_title containing non-latin characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following code to output Wordpress pages ordered by page title.

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'child_of' => $page,
    'parent' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$pages = get_pages($args);
```

It works fine except for pages starting with non-latin characters. Å gets sorted as A, it should be in the end, following our Swedish alphabet.

Comment: See answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529013/problem-sorting-swedish-characters-%C3%85-%C3%84-%C3%96-mysql)

Comment: @SevStryker The answer from Mad Marvin actually solved my issues. If you care to post it as a proper answer I will accept it.

Comment: It is not necessary, I just glad that helped you

Comment: I will add it myself then, just to keep the Q&A format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the regular `utf8_general_ci` does not solve this issue with Swedish letters. This SQL command solved the issues.

```
alter table wp_posts convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
$args = array(
   'orderby' => 'post_title',
   'order' => 'asc',
   'hierarchical' => 1,
   'child_of' => $page,
   'parent' => -1,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$pages = get_pages($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic plugin named Convert WP Database to UTF-8. I use it all the time. This plugin adds a sub-menu page named "UTF-8 DB Converter" to the Plugins Menu. Simple click on "Start converting" and the plugin will automatically execute the required SQL queries to alter the character set and collation of all your existing WordPress tables.

You only need to do it once per website, and the problem is fixed for good. You can then uninstall the plugin.

Although this plugin has always run without a hitch for me, it is proper practice to make a backup of your WordPress database before attempting this procedure.

Comment: Installed the plugin and i ran successfully, but unfortunately it did not solve my sort problems.

Comment: sry mate, I was just giving you my solution about this matter.