# Sort text in Swedish Alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

Hiii Everyone,

I have a list of locations in swedish text. I want to show that array of values in swedish alphabetical order. [By refering in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529013/problem-sorting-swedish-characters-%C3%85-%C3%84-%C3%96-mysql).

I changed my collation format to `utf8_swedish_ci`. And I inserted a list of locations. Then I use query to show location in alphabetical order.

```
SELECT * FROM location order by location ASC
```

Actual swedish alphabetical order is

A,B,C...Z And Å,Ä,Ö But im getting output in the order of

Ö,Å,Ä,A,B...Z if it may be in descending order it should be look like

Ö,Ä,Å,Z,Y,...A but the result im getting its totall confused.Please anyone help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
SELECT * FROM location order by location COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci ASC
```

Comment: There is no difference.still it is showing in wrong order